# How to explode a one row Spark dataframe in JSON format to multiple rows?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Context: I'm learning PySpark and I am trying to run a sentiment analysis on tweets. After loading the data (that is in JSON format), I want to store it in a Spark Dataframe for preprocessing (removing uncessary symbols/words). Currently, I'm using an intermediate step that I want to eliminate: I'm loading the JSON into a pandas DataFrame and then to the spark Dataframe and it all works well.

However, when loading the JSON directly onto a PySpark DataFrame, all the data is stored in one row only.

How I'm loading the data:

```
df = spark.read.json("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/json_twitter.json").select("full_text")
```

The df is constituted by only one row and one column (full_text) with the following format:

```
{"0": "Hello", "1": "Tweet","2": "Bye"}
```

How can I efficiently turn this into a "normal" dataframe, having one row for each word?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value inside `fulltext` is a string you may first convert it to a map type using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) example

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = df.withColumn("fulltext",F.from_json("fulltext",T.MapType(T.StringType(),T.StringType())))
```

before applying the [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function to split the values into multiple rows eg:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = df.select(F.explode("fulltext"))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|0  |Hello|
|1  |Tweet|
|2  |Bye  |
+---+-----+
```

#### Edit 1

If the value inside `fulltext` is  a struct, you may first

1. cast it to a string using `cast`
2. replace extra character braces using `regexp_replace`
3. split the string by comma using `split`
4. exploding the split value to get the desired rows using `explode`

eg

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = df.withColumn("fulltext",F.col("fulltext").cast("string"))
df.printSchema() # only for debugging purposes
df.show() # only for debugging purposes

df = df.withColumn("fulltext",F.explode(F.split(F.regexp_replace("fulltext","\\{|\\}",""),",")))

df.show() # only for debugging purposes
```

```
root
 |-- fulltext: string (nullable = false)

+-------------------+
|           fulltext|
+-------------------+
|{Hello, Tweet, Bye}|
+-------------------+

+--------+
|fulltext|
+--------+
|   Hello|
|   Tweet|
|     Bye|
+--------+
```

Comment: It is not a string. It is in the format above, in JSON. When running the first command, I'm obtaining the following error: "AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'entries' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`full_text`' is of struct type.;
'Project [from_json(MapType(StringType,StringType,true), full_text#356, Some(Etc/UTC)) AS full_text#417]
+- Project [full_text#356]".

Is there any workaround? Can I change its type to String?

Comment: Yes, you can change the date type to string before running the above with `df = df.withColumn("fulltext", F.col("fulltext").cast("string"))`

Comment: I tried doing that, but then when I run `df = df.withColumn("fulltext",F.from_json("fulltext",T.MapType(T.StringType(),T.StringType())))` I get a Dataframe with only one null value

Comment: @FHSilva I've updated the answer with an alternative approach. I was not original aware that `fulltext` was a struct in your scenario. In my environment, it was replicated as a `map` type. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It was exactly that, thank you!